# Contact Form UTF-8 encoding being ignored

Tags: php, ajax, utf-8

I am trying to send UTF-8 encoded texts from a form to a mail address, but all i get is garbage strings and i am totaly lost on where exactly i may have missed some UTF-8 "magic".

It sure feels like i have more UTF-8 lines in my code then everything else combined. Can anyone spot what i have missed? I went trough dozens of topics and pages that where about the same question, but i just don't find anything that i did not do already.

The php file uses:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Also i have set the mail header like this:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
```

The Ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "../php/process.php",
                type: "POST",
                scriptCharset: "utf-8",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                }
```

And i also tried setting AjaxSetup like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                scriptCharset: "utf-8",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
            });
```

All my files are encoded in UTF-8 (without bom) and my contact form is set to accept UTF-8 only. The HTML file also has the corresponding meta tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Edit for clarification: E-Mails can be all languages but asian. So German, French, English, ect. common letters work (don't they always?), but special chars don't work.

Checked in the Mail recived. Also the following is added to my form as stated above.

```
accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

So, what's left to try?

Comment: Good ole' [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)! When you say all you get is garbage strings, where are you inspecting that data? In PHP with some sort of output? In a database? In the browser tools?

Comment: is it all garbage? is the email in English or ?

Comment: Edit for clarifications added.

Comment: skip the code above and add a simple string in to the email body - if that works then its the form\web encodeing, gives you somewhere to start. use firebug to check the headers of the ajax request to make sure they are utf-8

Comment: before sending the email, have you tried maybe running the body through `utf_encode()`?

Comment: Ajax header is listed as UTF-8 in firebug. And i don't actually do anything to the string... so replacing the message with a fixed string did not change anything at all. Using utf_encode just garbeled the string in a different way.

Comment: sounds like its your mail call, you use mail() or?

Comment: **utf** in the mail header should be lowercase.

Comment: yes. That one is used in about every contact form tutorial i could dig up. Really tought id fail at something else then... encoding.

Comment: phpmailer is recommended over` mail` by most people

Comment: lower case does not change anything either. Guess i will look into phpmailer tomorrow then. Encoding really seems to be my bane. In whatever i do, encoding is taking the most time and is making the least sence.

Comment: while i don't send non English email i haven't had any issues with utf8 and phpmailer. if you find an answer please post it, i would like to know.

Comment: Ok, could not wait for tomorrow. phpmailer is really easy to use. A simple $mail->charset = "utf-8"; did the trick there. I even removed all of the above encodings and it still works with this simple line. Wanna put that up as an answer Dagon? Id love to mark using phpmailer as answer for this lol